# Get content from cell

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have UltraGrid and i need when i click on grid row to get content from specific column of that grid. For example if I click in cell of fourth column then i need to get value of first column of the same row where i clicked. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am not familiar with UltraGrid, but from what I just read at:

http://devcenter.infragistics.com/Support/KnowledgeBaseArticle.Aspx?ArticleID=1753

I believe you can simply get your value like I would from a VB.NET datagridview.

```
dim obj as object = UltraGrid1.Selected.Rows(0)..Cells.FromKey("Name of Cell").value
```

This should be a close proximity of what you need.